# Connect visio shapes in list

Tags: c#, visio

I try to connect a couple of shapes using this code:

```
Visio.Master ConnectionMaster = _masters.get_ItemU(connectorShapeName);
Visio.Shape Connector = _activePage.Drop(ConnectionMaster, 1, 1);

// get the start cell of connector
var b1 = (short) Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject;
var b2 = (short) Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D;
var b3 = (short) Visio.VisCellIndices.vis1DBeginX;
Visio.Cell beginXCell = Connector.get_CellsSRC(b1, b2, b3);

// and the end one
var e1 = (short) Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject;
var e2 = (short) Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D;
var e3 = (short) Visio.VisCellIndices.vis1DEndX;
Visio.Cell endXCell = Connector.get_CellsSRC(e1, e2, e3);

// get start point from first shape
var bt1 = (short) Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject;
var bt2 = (short) Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut;
var bt3 = (short) Visio.VisCellIndices.visXFormPinX;
var toBegin = fromShape.get_CellsSRC(bt1, bt2, bt3);

// get start point of second shape
var et1 = (short) Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject;
var et2 = (short) Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut;
var et3 = (short) Visio.VisCellIndices.visXFormPinX;
var toEnd = toShape.get_CellsSRC(et1, et2, et3);

// connect 
beginXCell.GlueTo(toBegin);
endXCell.GlueTo(toEnd);
```

This code works perfectly for shapes which were added to visio doc using this code:

```
Visio.Master shapeToDrop = _masters.get_ItemU(name);
Visio.Shape shape = _activePage.Drop(shapeToDrop, x, y);
```

But if shape was dropped into doc and then added to list, like this:

```
var shape = _activePage.DropIntoList(shapeToDrop, target, position);
```

I receive error: "An exception occurred."
in this code:

```
var toBegin = fromShape.get_CellsSRC(bt1, bt2, bt3);
```

So, what is the proper way to connect shapes that are in list? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you drop master you define variable as *shape*, but when you want get variable *toBegin* you use as object *fromShape*.

Comment: Drops shape and connect shapes functionality are in different methods. My fault if it wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is not connection related but to do with ensuring that categories match when dropping an item into a list.  Here's a short sample to demo the problem (starting with a blank drawing in Visio):

```
void Main()
{
    //Run this code against a blank drawing in Visio
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();

    var vDoc = vApp.ActiveDocument;
    var stencilDoc = vDoc.Application.Documents.OpenEx("wfctrl_m.vssx",
                                                       (short)Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenRO
                                                       + (short)Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);
    var vPag = vApp.ActivePage;

    var diagramServices = vDoc.DiagramServicesEnabled;
    vDoc.DiagramServicesEnabled = (int)Visio.VisDiagramServices.visServiceVersion140 
                                + (int)Visio.VisDiagramServices.visServiceVersion150;
    var shpList = vPag.Drop(stencilDoc.Masters.ItemU["List box"], 2.25, 9.5);
    var itemMaster = stencilDoc.Masters.ItemU["List box item"];

    // Drop two items in - this works because the item
    // shapes have the correct required categories ('Grid')
    vPag.DropIntoList(itemMaster, shpList, 1);
    vPag.DropIntoList(itemMaster, shpList, 1);

    // Now set the list's required categories to someting else
    shpList.CellsU["User.msvSDListRequiredCategories"].FormulaU = $"\"Bob\"";

    // Note an error is thrown here because the list item being
    // inserted does not contain the category 'Bob'
    try
    {           
        vPag.DropIntoList(itemMaster, shpList, 1);
    }
    catch (COMException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == -2032465763)
    {
        //Inappropriate source object for this action.
        Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message} - check matching categories in List and ListItem shapes");
    }

    vDoc.DiagramServicesEnabled = diagramServices;
}
```

You should probably write a quick check where you read the `User.msvShapeCategories` cell in the item shape and then check if those are amongst the required categeries in the list shape (`User.msvSDListRequiredCategories`).  See the '*Controlling container membership*' section of this post: [Custom Containers, Lists and Callouts in Visio 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visio/2010/01/12/custom-containers-lists-and-callouts-in-visio-2010/)for more details.

Just to add that if you want to connect the shapes in the list then you can either use your method above or something like this depending on the level of control you're after:

```
var item = vPag.DropIntoList(itemMaster, shpList, 1);
var target = vPag.DrawRectangle(4, 9, 6, 7.5);
item.AutoConnect(target, Visio.VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirNone);
```

Comment: I found than using
    Shape.ContainerProperties.InsertListMember(Shape shapeToDrop, int position)
solve two of my problem. First is that using this instead of DropIntoList allows me to connect shapes, and the second one is that I don't need to delete shape after I drop it into list

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I misread your question.  I thought you were getting the error on drop rather than the following toBegin assigment.  I think it's useful to have a full repo of code so it's easier to see where and what is failing.  Anyway, you're quite right, InsertListMember is another option.  I'm not quite clear on why you need to delete a shape, but I'm glad you're all fixed.